# Rails - Export records to downloadable excel file using axlsx gem (Keep MVC)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, export-to-excel

I have installed the axlsx gem successfully from https://github.com/randym/axlsx
Here is my controller code that I used to create an excel file through this gem.

But nothing happen with this code instead it shows me an error uninitialized mime

```
class Coaches::PaymentsController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_coach!

  # List all the payments
  def index
    if !params[:sort].blank?
      @payments = Payment.includes(:member).paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    else
      @payments = Payment.includes(:member).paginate(:page => params[:page], :order=>'id desc')
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      # Change format to xlsx
      format.xlsx
      format.json { render json: @payments }
    end
  end
end
```

Secondly,I try with this code:

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Buttons") do |sheet|
  @buttons.each do |button|
    sheet.add_row [button.name, button.category, button.price]
  end
end
```

But unfortunately, it does not work. Can anyone tell me only hint not a solution to do my task?

I have tried third times as per suggestion:

```
   def index
    if !params[:sort].blank?
      @payments = Payment.includes(:member).paginate(:page => params[:page], :order => sort_column + " " + sort_direction)
    else
      @payments = Payment.includes(:member).paginate(:page => params[:page], :order=>'id desc')
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.xlsx do
        p = Axlsx::Package.new
        wb = p.workbook
        wb.add_worksheet(name: "Your worksheet name") do |sheet|
          sheet.add_row ["First Column", "Second", "Third"]
          sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
          sheet.add_row [' preserving whitespace']
        end
        send_data p.to_stream.read, type: "application/xlsx", filename: "filename.xlsx"
      end
    end
  end
```

It thrown me http 406 error

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try using [axlsx_rails](https://github.com/straydogstudio/axlsx_rails) Gem with template.
In my case i used below configuration to make it work. and also a link with extension .xlsx to render it in xlsx format.

GEM FILE

```
gem 'axlsx', '~> 2.0'
gem "axlsx_rails"
```

controller file- payments_controller.rb

```
def download
    @payments = Payment.all
    respond_to do |format| 
       format.xlsx {render xlsx: 'download',filename: "payments.xlsx"}
    end
end
```

View file- download.xlsx.axlsx

```
wb = xlsx_package.workbook
wb.add_worksheet(name: "Payments") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["ID", "Notes","Amount($)","Deposit Date"]
    @payments.each do |payment|
        sheet.add_row [payment.id, payment.notes,payment.amount,payment.date_deposite]
    end
end
```

Comment: This is the best option for exporting to excel, it keeps MVC

Comment: Saved mime time so much.

Answer (score 22):

To prevent the uninitialized mime type error add the following file:

```
# config/initializers/mime_types.rb

Mime::Type.register "application/xlsx", :xlsx
```

And here is a short example of what to do to download the xlsx file:

```
format.xlsx do
  p = Axlsx::Package.new
  wb = p.workbook
  wb.add_worksheet(name: "Your worksheet name") do |sheet|
    # Add your stuff
  end
  send_data p.to_stream.read, type: "application/xlsx", filename: "filename.xlsx"
end
```

Comment: Daniel I have added code in mime still have 406 error

Comment: @DineshSaini what's the format you're requesting the xlsx file with? Is the response processed as XLSX? Can you show us the stacktrace of the request?

Comment: I have do nothing special all the codes are written above. Please tell me if you need any other code.

Comment: @DineshSaini can you include the stacktrace of the request that fails?

Comment: It dont show error. just simple page with 406 error. any other way to get stack

Comment: It seems to be traditional in open source projects to leave out a key bit of information. Without registering the mime type, nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Please set render false to HTML and avoid JSON instead use XLS and for trace, you can see terminal where you have started the rails.

Answer (score 2):

```
gem 'axlsx', '~> 2.0'
gem "axlsx_rails"
```

Comment: Right because there is need to be locked the version to support ROR 3.2.6

Answer (score 0):

I use gems.

```
gem 'axlsx', '~> 2.0'
gem "axlsx_rails"
```

But these gems occured a error. 
When I remove  'rubyzip' gem from Gemfile.lock , then `bundle install` problem has been solved.
Thanks.